# How to solve a system of two equations with three variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two equations:

$$100x+95y+10z = 54(x+y+z)$$
and
$$95x+10y+5z = 33(x+y+z)$$

How do I find the values of $x$, $y$, and $z$? I would like to use the elimination method. The answer should be:  $x=3, y=2, z=5$. This solution works in the equations.

I am trying to Eliminate ONE variable but, while cross checking the answer not matching with the given values (whereas the given values of x,y,z satisfies both sides when the values are substituted in above two equations).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The second equation is just the first one divided by $2$, so it doesn't provide new information

Comment: It has infinite answers

Comment: @Ginger bread : the system has definitely not "infinite answers", but an infinite number of solutions, which is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to use elimination to solve your system of linear equations. However we first must put the equations into standard form. For your first equation,
$$100x+95y+10z=54(x+y+z)$$
Multiply out the right side:
$$100x + 95y + 10z = 54x + 54y + 54z$$
Now subtract everything on the right hand side:
$$46x + 41y - 44z = 0 \qquad (1)$$
Do the same with your second equation:
$$95x+10y+5z=33(x+y+z)$$
$$95x+10y+5z=33x+33y+33z$$
$$62x - 23y - 28z = 0 \qquad (2)$$
Now we can do the elimination. We want to get the coefficient of the first variable $x$ in the first equation $(1)$ to be one. So divide equation (1) by $46$:
$$x + \frac{41}{46}y - \frac{22}{23}z = 0 \qquad (3)$$
We want to cancel the $x$ term from equation $(2)$ so we multiply $(3)$ by $62$:
$$62x + \frac{1271}{23}y - \frac{1364}{23}z = 0 \qquad (4)$$
Now subract equation $(4)$ from equation $(2)$:
$$\frac{1800}{23}y - \frac{720}{23}z = 0 \qquad (5)$$
We see that the $x$ term is indeed gone. Now we want to change the coefficient of the $y$ term to one, so multiply that last equation by $\frac{23}{1800}$:
$$y - \frac25z = 0 \qquad (6)$$
Solving for $y$ we get
$$y = \frac25z \qquad (7)$$
We are done with that equation. Now we want to eliminate the $y$ term from our transformed first equation, $(3)$. So we multiply equation $(6)$ by $\frac{41}{46}$:
$$\frac{41}{46}y - \frac{41}{115}z = 0 \qquad (8)$$
We subract equation $(8)$ from equation $(3)$:
$$x - \frac35z = 0 \qquad (9)$$
Solving that for $x$:
$$x = \frac35y \qquad (10)$$
Using $(7)$ and $(10)$ we have a complete answer: the ordered triple
$$\left(\frac35z, \  \frac25z, \ z\right)$$
So we see there are infinitely many solutions to your problem. Letting $z=5$ gives the solution that you show, but there are many others. Your answer is the one for the smallest integral values of the variables, but that is not what your problem asked for.

More information on $z$:

The variable $z$ can hold any value at all--it is completely arbitrary. Once you assign a particular value to $z$ then the variables $x$ and $y$ are determined. In other words, $z$ is a *parameter*. It is the key to all the solutions of your system of equations. Other parameters could be used, but the standard elimination technique leads to $z$ being the parameter.

Here is another way to look at it. The graph for your two equations in 3-dimensional space is a line. Choosing $z$ means choosing a particular point on that line.

Comment: Many thanks...it helped me..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve it for a specific value. It has infinite possibilities

Firstly you need atleast 3 DISTINCT equations if you need to solve for 3 variables.

In your question, not only did you provide only 2 equations, both of them are identical, divide by 2 and check.

So it's just a single equation in 3 variables. Unless there are certain constraints you have infinite solutions.

Are you sure there are no constraints, like all are natural numbers in some range?

Comment: @Jean Marie yes