# Two Equations with three variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve for two equations 
\begin{align}
10x+8y+1z &= 6.54(x+y+z) \\
 9x+6y+2z &= 5.31(x+y+z)
\end{align}

How to find $x, y, z$?

Answer should be: x=1, y=9, z=3

Comment: The system is underdetermined—more variables than equations—so unless there are some other conditions that you haven’t mentioned, there’s an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3656846/265466), albeit with a couple of different coefficients. Both of the systems are underdetermined, so do not have a unique solution without other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You answer is approximate. Note that the right hand side of the equations above does not correspond to integers.  The left hand side contains only integers.

To find $x,y,z$ you can use Gaussian elimination.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

There are online tools to do Gaussian elimination

https://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/equation/gaus/